# Importing CSV Data to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, csv

I need help importing this kind of information (CSV file).

```
Stanmore College,51.612767,-0.311072
```

It goes in this order: Place, Longitude, Latitude.

How do I import data from CSV file using the data above?

I created a `JFileChooser` & `ActionListener` for the user to load up the CSV file...

```
//---- btnLoadCSV ----
            btnLoadCSV.setText("Load from CSV");
            btnLoadCSV.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            btnLoadCSV.setMnemonic('L');
            btnLoadCSV.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    jfc = new JFileChooser();
                    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                            "CSV files (*csv)", "csv");
                    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
                    int ret = jfc.showOpenDialog(GoogleApp.this);
                    if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                        String s = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                }
            });
            panel1.add(btnLoadCSV, new TableLayoutConstraints(5, 1, 5, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));
```

When you import, it should take the data from the file and put the data in these `JLabels`
(But I don't know what to do from here...)

```
Place: label7 
Longitude: ttfLon 
Latitude: ttfLat
```

Thank you so much!

Full code/class (in case you need it):

```
import Task.*;
import Task.Manager.*;
import Task.ProgressMonitor.*;
import Task.Support.CoreSupport.*;
import Task.Support.GUISupport.*;
import com.jgoodies.forms.factories.*;
import info.clearthought.layout.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GoogleApp extends JFrame {
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
// data members
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
/** reference to task */
private SimpleTask _task;
/** this might be null. holds the image to display in a popup */
private BufferedImage _img;
/** this might be null. holds the text in case image doesn't display */
private String _respStr;

//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
// main method...
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Utils.createInEDT(GoogleApp.class);
}

//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
// constructor
//XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

private void doInit() {
  GUIUtils.setAppIcon(this, "burn.png");
  GUIUtils.centerOnScreen(this);
  setVisible(true);

  int W = 28, H = W;
  boolean blur = false;
  float alpha = .7f;

  try {
    btnGetMap.setIcon(ImageUtils.loadScaledBufferedIcon("ok1.png", W, H, blur, alpha));
    btnQuit.setIcon(ImageUtils.loadScaledBufferedIcon("charging.png", W, H, blur, alpha));
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }

  _setupTask();
}

/** create a test task and wire it up with a task handler that dumps output to the textarea */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void _setupTask() {

  TaskExecutorIF<ByteBuffer> functor = new TaskExecutorAdapter<ByteBuffer>() {
    public ByteBuffer doInBackground(Future<ByteBuffer> swingWorker,
                                     SwingUIHookAdapter hook) throws Exception
    {

      _initHook(hook);


      // get the uri for the static map
      String uri = MapLookup.getMap(Double.parseDouble(ttfLat.getText()),
                                    Double.parseDouble(ttfLon.getText()),
                                    Integer.parseInt(ttfSizeW.getText()),
                                    Integer.parseInt(ttfSizeH.getText()),
                                    Integer.parseInt(ttfZoom.getText())
      );
      sout("Google Maps URI=" + uri);

      // get the map from Google
      GetMethod get = new GetMethod(uri);
      new HttpClient().executeMethod(get);

      ByteBuffer data = HttpUtils.getMonitoredResponse(hook, get);

      try {
        _img = ImageUtils.toCompatibleImage(ImageIO.read(data.getInputStream()));
        sout("converted downloaded data to image...");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        _img = null;
        sout("The URI is not an image. Data is downloaded, can't display it as an image.");
        _respStr = new String(data.getBytes());
      }

      return data;
    }

    @Override public String getName() {
      return _task.getName();
    }
  };

  _task = new SimpleTask(
      new TaskManager(),
      functor,
      "HTTP GET Task",
      "Download an image from a URL",
      AutoShutdownSignals.Daemon
  );

  _task.addStatusListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      sout(":: task status change - " + ProgressMonitorUtils.parseStatusMessageFrom(evt));
      lblProgressStatus.setText(ProgressMonitorUtils.parseStatusMessageFrom(evt));
    }
  });

  _task.setTaskHandler(new
      SimpleTaskHandler<ByteBuffer>() {
        @Override public void beforeStart(AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler - beforeStart");
        }
        @Override public void started(AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler - started ");
        }
        /** {@link SampleApp#_initHook} adds the task status listener, which is removed here */
        @Override public void stopped(long time, AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler [" + task.getName() + "]- stopped");
          sout(":: time = " + time / 1000f + "sec");
          task.getUIHook().clearAllStatusListeners();
        }
        @Override public void interrupted(Throwable e, AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler [" + task.getName() + "]- interrupted - " + e.toString());
        }
        @Override public void ok(ByteBuffer value, long time, AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler [" + task.getName() + "]- ok - size=" + (value == null
              ? "null"
              : value.toString()));
          if (_img != null) {
            _displayImgInFrame();
          }
          else _displayRespStrInFrame();

        }
        @Override public void error(Throwable e, long time, AbstractTask task) {
          sout(":: taskHandler [" + task.getName() + "]- error - " + e.toString());
        }
        @Override public void cancelled(long time, AbstractTask task) {
          sout(" :: taskHandler [" + task.getName() + "]- cancelled");
        }
      }
  );
}

private SwingUIHookAdapter _initHook(SwingUIHookAdapter hook) {
  hook.enableRecieveStatusNotification(checkboxRecvStatus.isSelected());
  hook.enableSendStatusNotification(checkboxSendStatus.isSelected());

  hook.setProgressMessage(ttfProgressMsg.getText());

  PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      SwingUIHookAdapter.PropertyList type = ProgressMonitorUtils.parseTypeFrom(evt);
      int progress = ProgressMonitorUtils.parsePercentFrom(evt);
      String msg = ProgressMonitorUtils.parseMessageFrom(evt);

      progressBar.setValue(progress);
      progressBar.setString(type.toString());

      sout(msg);
    }
  };

  hook.addRecieveStatusListener(listener);
  hook.addSendStatusListener(listener);
  hook.addUnderlyingIOStreamInterruptedOrClosed(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      sout(evt.getPropertyName() + " fired!!!");
    }
  });

  return hook;
}

private void _displayImgInFrame() {

  final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google Static Map");
  GUIUtils.setAppIcon(frame, "71.png");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

  JLabel imgLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(_img));
  imgLbl.setToolTipText(MessageFormat.format("<html>Image downloaded from URI<br>size: w={0}, h={1}</html>",
                                             _img.getWidth(), _img.getHeight()));
  imgLbl.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { frame.dispose();}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
  });

  frame.setContentPane(imgLbl);
  frame.pack();

  GUIUtils.centerOnScreen(frame);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void _displayRespStrInFrame() {

  final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google Static Map - Error");
  GUIUtils.setAppIcon(frame, "69.png");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

  JTextArea response = new JTextArea(_respStr, 25, 80);
  response.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { frame.dispose();}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
  });

  frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(response));
  frame.pack();

  GUIUtils.centerOnScreen(frame);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}

/** simply dump status info to the textarea */
private void sout(final String s) {
  Runnable soutRunner = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      if (ttaStatus.getText().equals("")) {
        ttaStatus.setText(s);
      }
      else {
        ttaStatus.setText(ttaStatus.getText() + "\n" + s);
      }
    }
  };

  if (ThreadUtils.isInEDT()) {
    soutRunner.run();
  }
  else {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(soutRunner);
  }
}

private void startTaskAction() {
  try {
    _task.execute();
  }
  catch (TaskException e) {
    sout(e.getMessage());
  }
}


public GoogleApp() {
  initComponents();
  doInit();
}

private void quitProgram() {
  _task.shutdown();
  System.exit(0);
}

private void initComponents() {
  // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
  // Generated using JFormDesigner non-commercial license
  dialogPane = new JPanel();
  contentPanel = new JPanel();
  panel1 = new JPanel();
  label2 = new JLabel();
  ttfSizeW = new JTextField();
  label4 = new JLabel();
  ttfLat = new JTextField();
  btnGetMap = new JButton();
  btnLoadCSV = new JButton();
  label3 = new JLabel();
  ttfSizeH = new JTextField();
  label5 = new JLabel();
  ttfLon = new JTextField();
  btnQuit = new JButton();
  label1 = new JLabel();
  label6 = new JLabel();
  label7 = new JLabel();
  ttfZoom = new JTextField();
  scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
  ttaStatus = new JTextArea();
  panel2 = new JPanel();
  panel3 = new JPanel();
  checkboxRecvStatus = new JCheckBox();
  checkboxSendStatus = new JCheckBox();
  ttfProgressMsg = new JTextField();
  progressBar = new JProgressBar();
  lblProgressStatus = new JLabel();

  //======== this ========
  setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setTitle("GMaps App Loader");
  setIconImage(null);
  Container contentPane = getContentPane();
  contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  //======== dialogPane ========
  {
    dialogPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));
    dialogPane.setOpaque(false);
    dialogPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //======== contentPanel ========
    {
        contentPanel.setOpaque(false);
        contentPanel.setLayout(new TableLayout(new double[][] {
            {TableLayout.FILL},
            {TableLayout.PREFERRED, TableLayout.FILL, TableLayout.PREFERRED}}));
        ((TableLayout)contentPanel.getLayout()).setHGap(5);
        ((TableLayout)contentPanel.getLayout()).setVGap(5);

        //======== panel1 ========
        {
            panel1.setOpaque(false);
            panel1.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                new TitledBorder("Configure the inputs or load from CSV..."),
                Borders.DLU2_BORDER));
            panel1.setLayout(new TableLayout(new double[][] {
                {0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.05, TableLayout.FILL},
                {TableLayout.PREFERRED, TableLayout.PREFERRED, TableLayout.PREFERRED}}));
            ((TableLayout)panel1.getLayout()).setHGap(5);
            ((TableLayout)panel1.getLayout()).setVGap(5);

            //---- label2 ----
            label2.setText("Size Width");
            label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label2, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfSizeW ----
            ttfSizeW.setText("512");
            panel1.add(ttfSizeW, new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 0, 1, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- label4 ----
            label4.setText("Latitude");
            label4.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label4, new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 0, 2, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfLat ----
            ttfLat.setText("52.95907");
            panel1.add(ttfLat, new TableLayoutConstraints(3, 0, 3, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- btnGetMap ----
            btnGetMap.setText("Get Map");
            btnGetMap.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            btnGetMap.setMnemonic('G');
            btnGetMap.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    startTaskAction();
                }
            });
            panel1.add(btnGetMap, new TableLayoutConstraints(5, 0, 5, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- btnLoadCSV ----
            btnLoadCSV.setText("Load from CSV");
            btnLoadCSV.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            btnLoadCSV.setMnemonic('L');
            btnLoadCSV.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    jfc = new JFileChooser();
                    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                            "CSV files (*csv)", "csv");
                    jfc.setFileFilter(filter);
                    int ret = jfc.showOpenDialog(GoogleApp.this);
                    if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    {
                        File f = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                        String s = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                }
            });
            panel1.add(btnLoadCSV, new TableLayoutConstraints(5, 1, 5, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));


            //---- label3 ----
            label3.setText("Size Height");
            label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label3, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 1, 0, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfSizeH ----
            ttfSizeH.setText("512");
            panel1.add(ttfSizeH, new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- label5 ----
            label5.setText("Longitude");
            label5.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label5, new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 1, 2, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfLon ----
            ttfLon.setText("-1.182468");
            panel1.add(ttfLon, new TableLayoutConstraints(3, 1, 3, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- btnQuit ----
            btnQuit.setText("Quit");
            btnQuit.setMnemonic('Q');
            btnQuit.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            btnQuit.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            btnQuit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    quitProgram();
                }
            });
            panel1.add(btnQuit, new TableLayoutConstraints(5, 2, 5, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- label1 ----
            label1.setText("Zoom");
            label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label1, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 2, 0, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfZoom ----
            ttfZoom.setText("17");
            ttfZoom.setToolTipText("Enter Zoom Number. Max 19.");
            panel1.add(ttfZoom, new TableLayoutConstraints(1, 2, 1, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- Spare ----
            label6.setText("Place");
            label6.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            panel1.add(label6, new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 2, 2, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- Sparetextbox ----
            label7.setText("-- CSV Only --");
            panel1.add(label7, new TableLayoutConstraints(3, 2, 3, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));
        }
        contentPanel.add(panel1, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

        //======== scrollPane1 ========
        {
            scrollPane1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("System.out - displays all status and progress messages, etc."));
            scrollPane1.setOpaque(false);

            //---- ttaStatus ----
            ttaStatus.setBorder(Borders.createEmptyBorder("1dlu, 1dlu, 1dlu, 1dlu"));
            ttaStatus.setToolTipText("<html>Task progress updates (messages) are displayed here,<br>along with any other output generated by the Task.<html>");
            scrollPane1.setViewportView(ttaStatus);
        }
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane1, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 1, 0, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

        //======== panel2 ========
        {
            panel2.setOpaque(false);
            panel2.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                new TitledBorder("Status - control progress reporting"),
                Borders.DLU2_BORDER));
            panel2.setLayout(new TableLayout(new double[][] {
                {0.45, TableLayout.FILL, 0.45},
                {TableLayout.PREFERRED, TableLayout.PREFERRED}}));
            ((TableLayout)panel2.getLayout()).setHGap(5);
            ((TableLayout)panel2.getLayout()).setVGap(5);

            //======== panel3 ========
            {
                panel3.setOpaque(false);
                panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

                //---- checkboxRecvStatus ----
                checkboxRecvStatus.setText("Enable \"Recieve\"");
                checkboxRecvStatus.setOpaque(false);
                checkboxRecvStatus.setToolTipText("Task will fire \"send\" status updates");
                checkboxRecvStatus.setSelected(true);
                panel3.add(checkboxRecvStatus);

                //---- checkboxSendStatus ----
                checkboxSendStatus.setText("Enable \"Send\"");
                checkboxSendStatus.setOpaque(false);
                checkboxSendStatus.setToolTipText("Task will fire \"recieve\" status updates");
                panel3.add(checkboxSendStatus);
            }
            panel2.add(panel3, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 0, 0, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- ttfProgressMsg ----
            ttfProgressMsg.setText("Connecting to Google Maps...");
            ttfProgressMsg.setToolTipText("Set the task progress message here");
            panel2.add(ttfProgressMsg, new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 0, 2, 0, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- progressBar ----
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBar.setString("progress %");
            progressBar.setToolTipText("% progress is displayed here");
            panel2.add(progressBar, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 1, 0, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));

            //---- lblProgressStatus ----
            lblProgressStatus.setText("task status listener");
            lblProgressStatus.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            lblProgressStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            lblProgressStatus.setToolTipText("Task status messages are displayed here when the task runs");
            panel2.add(lblProgressStatus, new TableLayoutConstraints(2, 1, 2, 1, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));
        }
        contentPanel.add(panel2, new TableLayoutConstraints(0, 2, 0, 2, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL, TableLayoutConstraints.FULL));
    }
    dialogPane.add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  contentPane.add(dialogPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  setSize(675, 485);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
}

// JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
// Generated using JFormDesigner non-commercial license
private JPanel dialogPane;
private JPanel contentPanel;
private JPanel panel1;
private JLabel label2;
private JTextField ttfSizeW;
private JLabel label4;
private JTextField ttfLat;
private JButton btnGetMap;
private JButton btnLoadCSV;
private JLabel label3;
private JTextField ttfSizeH;
private JLabel label5;
private JTextField ttfLon;
private JButton btnQuit;
private JLabel label1;
private JLabel label6;
private JLabel label7;
private JTextField ttfZoom;
private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
private JTextArea ttaStatus;
private JPanel panel2;
private JPanel panel3;
private JCheckBox checkboxRecvStatus;
private JCheckBox checkboxSendStatus;
private JTextField ttfProgressMsg;
private JFileChooser jfc;
private JProgressBar progressBar;
private JLabel lblProgressStatus;
}
```

Comment: Use a `JTable`.  If that does not answer your question, ..what is your question?

Comment: No, the question was how do I import data from CSV file using the data above? Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. :)

Comment: OK.  I'd say, look to a CSV API to load the CSV and provide access to the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply read the whole thing as a string and split it. Try what is below

```
import java.util.io
import java.util.scanner

File file = new File("file source");
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

fileString = fileScanner.nextLine();
info = fileString.split(",");
```